# Unity 2020.1 WebGL не запускается билд

Tags: unity3d, webgl

После билда виснет на 99% в браузере и выдает ошибку
Uncaught ReferenceError: unityFramework is not defined at HTMLScriptElement.script.onload (WebGL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

фикс: ProjectSettings->Player->Publishing Settings->Compression Format ->> Disabled